# Signal R Chat application on IIS not working

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am trying to build a SignalR application in Visual Studio 2012. My problem is that it works well under Visual Studio debug (using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7), but when I try to deploy the application on IIS 7.5 , the app does nothing more than displaying the index.html page.

my Index.html page is like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Css/ChatStyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Css/JQueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">





    <!--Script references. -->

      <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>



    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js"></script>

    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            setScreen(false);

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;

            registerClientMethods(chatHub);

            // Start Hub
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

                registerEvents(chatHub)

            });

        });

        function setScreen(isLogin) {

            if (!isLogin) {

                $("#divChat").hide();
                $("#divLogin").show();
            }
            else {

                $("#divChat").show();
                $("#divLogin").hide();
            }

        }

        function registerEvents(chatHub) {

            $("#btnStartChat").click(function () {

                var name = $("#txtNickName").val();
                if (name.length > 0) {
                    chatHub.server.connect(name);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please enter name");
                }

            });


            $('#btnSendMsg').click(function () {

                var msg = $("#txtMessage").val();
                if (msg.length > 0) {

                    var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();
                    chatHub.server.sendMessageToAll(userName, msg);
                    $("#txtMessage").val('');
                }
            });


            $("#txtNickName").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $("#btnStartChat").click();
                }
            });

            $("#txtMessage").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $('#btnSendMsg').click();
                }
            });


        }

        function registerClientMethods(chatHub) {

            // Calls when user successfully logged in
            chatHub.client.onConnected = function (id, userName, allUsers, messages) {

                setScreen(true);

                $('#hdId').val(id);
                $('#hdUserName').val(userName);
                $('#spanUser').html(userName);

                // Add All Users
                for (i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {

                    AddUser(chatHub, allUsers[i].ConnectionId, allUsers[i].UserName);
                }

                // Add Existing Messages
                for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                    AddMessage(messages[i].UserName, messages[i].Message);
                }


            }

            // On New User Connected
            chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected = function (id, name) {

                AddUser(chatHub, id, name);
            }


            // On User Disconnected
            chatHub.client.onUserDisconnected = function (id, userName) {

                $('#' + id).remove();

                var ctrId = 'private_' + id;
                $('#' + ctrId).remove();


                var disc = $('<div class="disconnect">"' + userName + '" logged off.</div>');

                $(disc).hide();
                $('#divusers').prepend(disc);
                $(disc).fadeIn(200).delay(2000).fadeOut(200);

            }

            chatHub.client.messageReceived = function (userName, message) {

                AddMessage(userName, message);
            }


            chatHub.client.sendPrivateMessage = function (windowId, fromUserName, message) {

                var ctrId = 'private_' + windowId;


                if ($('#' + ctrId).length == 0) {

                    createPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, windowId, ctrId, fromUserName);

                }

                $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + fromUserName + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');

                // set scrollbar
                var height = $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage')[0].scrollHeight;
                $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').scrollTop(height);

            }

        }

        function AddUser(chatHub, id, name) {

            var userId = $('#hdId').val();

            var code = "";

            if (userId == id) {

                code = $('<div class="loginUser">' + name + "</div>");

            }
            else {

                code = $('<a id="' + id + '" class="user" >' + name + '<a>');

                $(code).dblclick(function () {

                    var id = $(this).attr('id');

                    if (userId != id)
                        OpenPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, id, name);

                });
            }

            $("#divusers").append(code);

        }

        function AddMessage(userName, message) {
            $('#divChatWindow').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + userName + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');

            var height = $('#divChatWindow')[0].scrollHeight;
            $('#divChatWindow').scrollTop(height);
        }

        function OpenPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, id, userName) {

            var ctrId = 'private_' + id;

            if ($('#' + ctrId).length > 0) return;

            createPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, id, ctrId, userName);

        }

        function createPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, userId, ctrId, userName) {

            var div = '<div id="' + ctrId + '" class="ui-widget-content draggable" rel="0">' +
                       '<div class="header">' +
                          '<div  style="float:right;">' +
                              '<img id="imgDelete"  style="cursor:pointer;" src="/Images/delete.png"/>' +
                           '</div>' +

                           '<span class="selText" rel="0">' + userName + '</span>' +
                       '</div>' +
                       '<div id="divMessage" class="messageArea">' +

                       '</div>' +
                       '<div class="buttonBar">' +
                          '<input id="txtPrivateMessage" class="msgText" type="text"   />' +
                          '<input id="btnSendMessage" class="submitButton button" type="button" value="Send"   />' +
                       '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

            var $div = $(div);

            // DELETE BUTTON IMAGE
            $div.find('#imgDelete').click(function () {
                $('#' + ctrId).remove();
            });

            // Send Button event
            $div.find("#btnSendMessage").click(function () {

                $textBox = $div.find("#txtPrivateMessage");
                var msg = $textBox.val();
                if (msg.length > 0) {

                    chatHub.server.sendPrivateMessage(userId, msg);
                    $textBox.val('');
                }
            });

            // Text Box event
            $div.find("#txtPrivateMessage").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $div.find("#btnSendMessage").click();
                }
            });

            AddDivToContainer($div);

        }

        function AddDivToContainer($div) {
            $('#divContainer').prepend($div);

            $div.draggable({

                handle: ".header",
                stop: function () {

                }
            });

            ////$div.resizable({
            ////    stop: function () {

            ////    }
            ////});

        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        ABC BANK CHAT ROOM
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="divContainer">
        <div id="divLogin" class="login">
            <div>
                Your Name:<br />
            <input id="txtNickName" type="text" class="textBox" />
            </div>
            <div id="divButton">
                <input id="btnStartChat" type="button" class="submitButton" value="Start Chat" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="divChat" class="chatRoom">
            <div class="title">
                Welcome to Chat Room [<span id='spanUser'></span>]

            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div id="divChatWindow" class="chatWindow">
                </div>
                <div id="divusers" class="users">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="messageBar">
                <input class="textbox" type="text" id="txtMessage" />
                <input id="btnSendMsg" type="button" value="Send" class="submitButton" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
        <input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried some of the methods listed here: Signalr/Hub not loading in IIS 7 but working correctly in Visual Studio, but none of them seem to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, chiranjit

Comment: Have you tried the things listed here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms? Specifically, running in integrated mode and enabling extensionless URLs?

Comment: yea. i checked that one also. but still not working in iis.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove all the leading slashes "/"
(Ans maybe also upgrade to at least jquery-1.9.1)

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Css/ChatStyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/JQueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />


<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>


<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js"></script>

<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```